# Auto insert html code in textarea with onClick event

Tags: php

I am using this code to insert text but now i want to add html code in textfield as well.

```
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat" value="Bitcoin" onclick="insertText('input-comment', '<iframe src="invoice.php?address=3NUcGsurfneJxMC3vb5hWwgjg5ytTP9daB&amount=10&id=109" width="800px" height="800px" frameborder="0px"></iframe>');">
```

It is working fine when i put text in it but doesn't work any more when i add this html code. This html code(iframe code) should automatically inserted in textarea on button click.

My js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function insertText(elemID, text)
  {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
    elem.innerHTML += text;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you need to escape the quotes within the function parameters

Comment: are there any errors in the console? Can you include your js function `insertText`?

Comment: added above! 
`<script type="text/javascript">
      function insertText(elemID, text)
      {
        var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
        elem.innerHTML += text;
      }
    </script>`

Comment: check the below.... if you use single quotes and escape them in the function parameter it's ok

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the double quotes in the function parameters, like:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat" value="Bitcoin" onclick="insertText( 'input-comment', '<iframe src=\'invoice.php?address=3NUcGsurfneJxMC3vb5hWwgjg5ytTP9daB&amount=10&id=109\' width=\'800px\' height=\'800px\' frameborder=\'0px\'></iframe>' )" />
```

Corrected the previous code - this seems to work

Comment: WORKED! Thank you friend for helping me out